# How I get the current working directory with inverted slash?

Tags: bash, filenames, string

I'm trying to write a script to import a font in Wine, because I put the font in wine's `c:\Windows\Fonts`, but Wine doesn't read it if I don't import from the reg file:

```
"Font Name"="Z:\path\to\my\wineprefix\c:\Windows\Fonts\file.ttf"
```

And I don't know how to change the `/` to `\`, using `$(pwd)` or `$PWD`. Does someone know how I can replace the slash with a backslash?

I have a trouble with echo and with the output file. In my bash script I have this

```
RUTA=""$( cd -P "$( dirname "$" )" && pwd )""
RUTAINVERSA=$(printf '%s\n' "${PWD//\//\\}")
```

Well I has try with the follows:

1 :

```
echo 'REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Wine\\Fonts\\External Fonts]
"Courier New"="'"Z:\\$RUTAINVERSA\\wine\\data\\dosdevices\\c:\\windows\\Fonts\\cour.ttf"'"
"Courier New Bold"="'"Z:\\$RUTAINVERSA\\wine\\data\\dosdevices\\c:\\windows\\Fonts\\courbd.ttf"'"' >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
```

The result in the past are: `c:\Windows\Fonts`, and I don't know what happened with the rest with `\file.ttf`.

2 :

```
echo >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
echo "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Wine\\Fonts\\External Fonts]" >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
echo "Courier New"="c:\\windows\\Fonts\\cour.ttf" >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
echo "Courier New Bold"="c:\\windows\\Fonts\\courbd.ttf" >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
```

The result are: Courier New c:windowsFontcour.tff Courier New Bold c:widowsFontscourbd.ttf

3 :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Wine\\Fonts\\External Fonts]
"Courier New"="'"c:\\\windows\\\Fonts\\\cour.ttf"'"
"Courier New Bold"="'"c:\\\windows\\\Fonts\\\courbd.ttf"'" ' >> "$ARREGLOS/Fuentes.reg"
```

and it's the same the first `c:\windows\Fonts`, I don't know why the path are not full in the variable result.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but changing the slashes is easy:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${PWD//\//\\}"
\home\terdon
```

This is using ksh's string manipulation capabilities [also available in `bash`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). Specifically, `${foo//bar/baz/}` will replace all occurrences of the string `bar` with `baz` in the variable `$foo`. Since `/` and `\` are special characters, they need to be escaped (`\\` and `\/`) for this to work with them. The above is equivalent to:

```
pwd | sed 's#/#\\#g'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`sed`** to convert all `/` into `\` by following command:

```
sed  's/\//\\/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo $PWD | sed  's/\//\\/g'
\home\pandya
```

Another way is to use **`tr`**:

```
tr '/' '\\'
```

By above command, `tr` convertes all `/` with`\`; Example:

```
$ echo $PWD | tr '/' '\\'
\home\pandya
```